# Semi transparent Instruction activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to display instruction activity when user opens the app for the first time. I am using shared preference for that. Whatever I am doing so far is working. But I think my way of achieving this is not right.
What I am following:

- I am drawing a transparent instruction image(with instructions) in photoshop.
- Checking if user is opening that page for the first time(using shared preference).
- Displaying that particular image in an activity with translucent theme

  `private void showFrontPageGuideIfFirstTime(){
    if(!prefKeeper.getBoolean(PreferenceKey.FRONT_GUIDE)){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowGuide.class);
       intent.putExtra(BACKGROUND_KEY, R.drawable.front_page_png);
       this.startActivity(intent);
       prefKeeper.putBoolean(PreferenceKey.FRONT_GUIDE, true);
    }
  }`

And my instruction page looks something like(made in photoshop):
[The Instruction Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Jdi.png)

But I think by this way it would not work in all smart phone screens.
Where am I wrong, and what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe one image for each tap icon, then with a relative layout you can bind these images to its respective corner.

Comment: If you are looking for an onboarding screen check it out, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-onboarding-screens-for-android-apps--cms-24465

Comment: @Gerard Reches: What if I want to display these images over ActionBar and menus in DrawerLayout?

Comment: @Anoop Kanyan: Hey, thanks for that. But I don't require that. I want to display images as the user goes through my app. When the user opens a page for the first time, he is oblivious of the controls. There I want to display those images.

Comment: If its the first time :You should use a framelayout and dynamically attach childs to it which I assume would be the two images you have and then a relativelayout that basically has a translucent background. 
If its not the first time :You never attach the children to the framelayout and everything works without the overlay.

Comment: @RishabhSharma That would be more difficult. If the fragments appear above the previous activity, maybe it's possible to open a fragment with transparent background in full screen. It's just a theory, I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation as below

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.excogitation.example_mvptdd.MainActivity">

   <!-- Include your layout here-->
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In your activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Parent FrameLayout
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framelayout);

    // Dynamically create a relativelayout which will be appended to framelayout
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams
            .MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    relativeLayout.setAlpha(0.7f);
    relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // remove the whole relativelayout on click
            frameLayout.removeView(relativeLayout);
        }
    });

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    // Place 1st 30x40 ImageView at (50,60) coordinates
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    params.leftMargin = 20;
    params.topMargin = 50;
    final ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_star));
    // Add 1st imageview to relative layout
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView1, params);

    // Place 2nd 30x40 ImageView at (100,60) coordinates
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(120, 120);
    params.leftMargin = 800;
    params.topMargin = 450;
    final ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_star));
    // Add 2nd imageview to relative layout
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView2, params);

    // finally add it ot the framelayout
    frameLayout.addView(relativeLayout);


 }
}
```

Ofcourse you should modify this code with your own images and colors and interactions. Its just a simple working version that is better than loading a whole image upfront when you all you want is smaller helper images on a translucent background for the instructions.

Also you in this way you make things more Android-ish and editable. You can add more children to the relative layout like a textview to include instructions.

**Screenshot on load of app and hence the relative layout as an overlay.**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot on click/touch , the relative layout is removed.**

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: thanks, love this tricky. could you please explain how to display this transparent layout only 1 time when apps installed?

Comment: Use sharedpreferences to setup a flag and when you have displayed this flip the flag. Next time the app opens the flag would not be true and this wont be shown.